# Undefined offset: 1 with array when reading data

Tags: php

plz help me
i have one function for crop image, and give size for array But it does not work :|

```
function image_resize($file, $replace, $size, $quality)
{
    $size_array =   explode('x', $size);

    $width      =   $size_array[0];
    $height     =   $size_array[1];
    $format     =   strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));
    ...
}
```

include function:

```
image_resize($image_url, $thumbnail_url, '449×252', '70');
```

error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 1
>
> Filename: helpers/image_resize_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 11

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting by the letter "x", but your width*height string contains the mathematical multiplication symbol "×". Therefore, `explode()` will return an array containing a single item.

Either explode by `'×'` or send the width*height string with a literal `x` character: `'449x252'`.